# How to Debug Open Source Projects on Eclipse 3.7

Tags: eclipse, open-source

I have downloaded "Totem" movie player source code. I red the INSTALL file but have not found information about how to import the project into an IDE. 
I have uncompressed Totem Source Code then imported the root directory using "File System".
When I build the project I get an error message shown below:

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project Totem ****

make all 
make: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.

**** Build Finished ****
```

One more question: On which IDEs do developers develop open source projects based on C/C++?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the scripts in the source tree from terminal.

See `autogen.sh`.

Also be sure to have solved your dependencies.

Maybe then it will work in Eclipse.

Otherwise, use your terminal.